# Sorting an array of objects in MongoDB collection

Tags: arrays, mongodb, sorting, object

I have a collection in a MongoDB with a document like below:

```
{
  "_id": "63269e0f85bfd011e989d0f7",
  "name": "Aravind Krishna",
  "mobile": 7309454620,
  "email": "akaravindk59@gmail.com",
  "password": "$2b$12$0dOE/0wj6uX604h3DZpGxuO/L.fZg7KCm7mOGsNMkarSaeG2C/Wvq",
  "orders": [
    {
      "paymentIntentId": "pi_3LjFDtSHVloG65Ul0exLkzsO",
      "cart": [array],
      "amount": 3007,
      "created": 1663475717,
      "_id": "6326a01344f26617fc1a65d6"
    },
    {
      "paymentIntentId": "pi_3LjFFUSHVloG65Ul1FQHlZ9H",
      "cart": [array],
      "amount": 389,
      "created": 1663475816,
      "_id": "6326a07744f26617fc1a65d8"
    }
  ],
  "__v": 0
}
```

I wanted to get only the orders array sorted by the **created** property in both ascending and descending manner. As we can see here that orders field inside this document is an array of objects. Please give a solution if you have one. I tried the sortArray method but it is giving an error. Please help.

For some assistance the output should look something like this:

```
    {
  "_id": "63269e0f85bfd011e989d0f7",
  "orders": [
    {
      "paymentIntentId": "pi_3LjFDtSHVloG65Ul0exLkzsO",
      "cart": [array],
      "amount": 3007,
      "created": 1663475717,
      "_id": "6326a01344f26617fc1a65d6"
    },
    {
      "paymentIntentId": "pi_3LjFFUSHVloG65Ul1FQHlZ9H",
      "cart": [array],
      "amount": 389,
      "created": 1663475816,
      "_id": "6326a07744f26617fc1a65d8"
    }
  ]
}
```

See, I got only the orders field but I want it sorted by the created property value both ascending and descending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned the best way to achieve this is to use [$sortArray](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sortArray/), I'm assuming the error you're getting is a version mismatch as this operator was only recently added at version 5.2.

The other way to achieve the same result as not as pleasant, you need to `$unwind` the array, `$sort` the results and then `$group` to restore structure, then it's easy to add the "other" order by using `$reverseArray` although I recommend instead of duplicating your data you just handle the "reverse" requirement in code, overall the pipeline will look like so:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$orders"
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      "orders.created": 1
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      asc_orders: {
        $push: "$orders"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      desc_orders: {
        "$reverseArray": "$asc_orders"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/YqtV_qjdgEH)